# Letting user draw AOI or draw points for tool input In ArcMap script tool?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, feature-set

I have a python script which uses a point file to do some spatial analysis. After opening the tool in arcmap, I would like the user to be able to just click points on the map to generate the data. I found something about "Interactive Feature Input", which I believe is what I want. However, the information I found was pretty much useless. Currently, the tool just uses an existing point file.

I use ArcGIS Desktop 10.4 or 10.6.

Comment: This might help https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011690

Comment: Above comment will work for a python add-in, but for a python script tool you can look at the Feature Set parameter datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @user2856 noted, you can use a Feature Set variable in a script tool.  I found this to work the most effectively with a ModelBuilder implementation, which I then run out of an ArcToolbox just like a normal script.  The model built will be simple, even if you're unfamiliar with ModelBuilder:  a single input parameter which is the Feature Set, then the rest of your script which that Feature Set is directed towards.

You can first open a blank Model Builder session, drag and drop your existing script from Catalog, and then click Insert -> Variable -> Feature Set to create a Feature Set variable alongside the script:
[image]

Open the Feature Set and specify a layer to import schema and symbology from - this will allow not just for a set map display, but more importantly point, line or polygon type.

[image]

You can open the model as you would a normal script out of Catalog.  If you have additional parameters, you can add them as variables in ModelBuilder and create links to your script file object, specifying "Model Input Parameter".  Note that you'll have to do this for each input and output variable, in the order they appear in the script.

[image]